# Using Expect for Groovy to automate an interactive CLI session

Tags: java

I'm using this code:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Expect+for+Groovy

to attempt to automate a python based CLI.

My test main function is below.

Running this however, it seems that it never actually reads data from the process. 
If I change the process to /bin/ls and expect some filename, it will work correctly, which leads me to believe it cant handle the fact that python is waiting for input, while /bin/ls closes the stream and flushes it.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
public static void test2(String[] args){
    println "Main"
    def builder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/python");
    builder.redirectErrorStream()
    builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);
    builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);

    def expectSession = new IOSession(builder.start());
    expectSession.expect(">>>");
    expectSession.send("print(%d) % (1+1)")
    expectSession.expect("2");
    expectSession.send("quit()");
    expectSession.close();
    println "Done...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source for `IOSession` it looks like this might be a bug in the constructor. Try:

```
def expectSession = new IOSession();
expectSession.addProcess(builder.start());
```

Also, you have to add `\r` to the end of the strings you are sending.

Comment: While that may be an issue, I dont think thats the reason the expectSession cant seem to read from /use/bin/pythons output stream?

Comment: @ColinGrogan Have you confirmed that your program is blocking on the first `expect` and not the second? I would expect it to block on the second because of the lack of a `\r` in the send. Python won't send you any data after the inital `>>>` until you give it a command terminated with `\r`.

Comment: Hi. Yep. I've edited the code around the first expect call to:
    def expectSession = new IOSession(builder.start());
    println "Before expect";
    expectSession.expect(">>>");
    println "After expect";
    expectSession.send("print(%d) % (1+1)\r\n");

And the output prints "Before expect", but doesnt get to "After expect"

Comment: @ColinGrogan It might be a bug in `IOSession`. I've updated my answer with a suggestion.  Also don't send `\r\n`, just `\r`, even on windows. It's not a line terminator you're sending, it's just the key code for the enter key.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back. I've tried the addProcess() method, however it still doesnt work. 
In InputSession.setInputStream, I've edited it to print a line before and after the total = inputStream.read(inputData, 0, buffersize) line.
Only the first string gets printed, so this line is blocking, so I'm *guessing* that this line blocks as /usr/bin/python isn't flushing it's stream?

Comment: @ColinGrogan It works fine when I use the command line expect so it's not python that is the problem. If I get time I will try to setup a groovy env and see if I can recreate the issue.

Comment: Thanks.
 I've tested this on the command line expect also, and it just works. Sadly that isnt a player for me as need to support windows, where this groovy code works, at least for simple cases.